# nltk.download() logs out on OS X

Tags: macos, python, macos-mojave, python-gui

I have a macbook running OS X 10.14.6, Python 3.7.3.

When I try run interactive installer from NLTK python package, following the steps from: http://www.nltk.org/data.html in my terminal, after

```
>> nltk.download()
```

Instead of opening NLTK Downloader in a new window, I get logged out (ok, i assume something related to GUI crashes at this point). There is a hack to run

```
nltk.download_shell()
```

instead, as it will not try to open GUI installer, but I still want to figure out why GUI won't work for me. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a bug report, have you asked the author or maintainer?

Comment: I thought something might be wrong with my set up as python fails to open a new window (as I understand this...), but thanks for the suggestion, will try.

Comment: @MikeK I am also facing this issue. The error is ```nltk.d2019-08-28 18:23:42.367 python[77461:252794] +[NSXPCSharedListener endpointForReply:withListenerName:]: an error occurred while attempting to obtain endpoint for listener 'ClientCallsAuxiliary': Connection interrupted
2019-08-28 18:23:42.368 python[77461:252563] HIToolbox: received notification of WindowServer event port death.
2019-08-28 18:23:42.368 python[77461:252563] port matched the WindowServer port created in BindCGSToRunLoop```

Comment: For anybody who is getting here: 
https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2357